# Converting string variable data to quarterly time series data

Tags: type-conversion, time-series, stata

I have this type of a data set in Stata:

```
date       y   x

Q1 1990   2    4
Q2 1990   2    5
Q3 1990   6    66
Q4 1990   88   99
Q1 1991   12   24
Q2 1991   42   53
Q3 1991   63   66
Q4 1991   8    39
```

and so on until Q4 2014.

I would like to do time-series analysis in Stata and was wondering how I should first convert my date variable (a string variable) into a time series variable in Stata.

Comment: The code added here in an edit should on the face of it have worked, so I don't know where the question comes from.

Comment: The question was before I figured it out.

Comment: Good, but you could have posted your own answer and got credit for it. I am not complaining or criticising, just underlining that it is fine to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What code did you try? Questions without code are widely considered off-topic here. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Functions for converting strings to numeric dates are documented at `help dates`. The only small twist here is that you need to ignore the `Q`. Using `quarterly()` is easier in your case, but `yq()` is also available.

```
. input str7 date 

          date
  1.  "Q1 1990"  
  2.  "Q2 1990"  
  3.  "Q3 1990"  
  4.  "Q4 1990"  
  5.  "Q1 1991"  
  6.  "Q2 1991"  
  7.  "Q3 1991"  
  8.  "Q4 1991"
  9. end 

. gen qdate1 = quarterly(substr(date, 2, .), "QY") 

. gen qdate2 = yq(real(word(date, 2)), real(substr(date, 2, 1)))

. format qdate? %tq 

. assert qdate1 == qdate2

. list 

     +---------------------------+
     |    date   qdate1   qdate2 |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | Q1 1990   1990q1   1990q1 |
  2. | Q2 1990   1990q2   1990q2 |
  3. | Q3 1990   1990q3   1990q3 |
  4. | Q4 1990   1990q4   1990q4 |
  5. | Q1 1991   1991q1   1991q1 |
     |---------------------------|
  6. | Q2 1991   1991q2   1991q2 |
  7. | Q3 1991   1991q3   1991q3 |
  8. | Q4 1991   1991q4   1991q4 |
     +---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing this:

```
*Converting the data to time series
d

list

gen qdate = yq(real(substr(date, -4, 4)), real(substr(date, 2, 1)))

format qdate %tq

l

*Declare data as time series

tsset qdate
```

Comment: This is similar to the `yq()` solution in my answer with the difference of using `substr()` rather than `word()` to extract the year as a string.